# MySQL to group a column's values to a single cell value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, temp-tables

I have a query that return data with 10 columns and in which only one column value is unique for every row and all the other column values will be repeated for few rows each.

Eg:
**Column 1 | Column 2 | column 3 | column 4 | column 5 | Column 6**

          Sony     |    Xperia   |   stack      |   ask        | question   |    XYZ

          Sony     |    Xperia   |   stack      |   ask        | question   |    ABC

          Sony     |    Xperia   |   stack      |   ask        | question   |    123

          Nexus   |   Android  |   stack      |   ask        | question   |    POI

          Nexus   |   Android  |   stack      |   ask        | question   |    KILL

I want the result to be as -

Eg: **Column 1 | Column 2 | column 3 | column 4 | column 5 | Column 6**

          Sony     |    Xperia   |   stack      |   ask        | question   |    XYZ, ABC, 123

          Nexus   |   Android  |   stack      |   ask        | question   |    POI, KILL

Can you guys please help me in achieving this through mysql query ?? Just a hint of the possibilities would do.
I got the values in sorted order so that the "to be grouped" rows will always come consecutively.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this using aggregation and `group_concat()`:

```
select column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, group_concat(column6) as column6
from query q
group by column1, column2, column3, column4, column5;
```